# monero-wallet-gui on android playstore

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, android-wallet, android

As of today, what would be required to deploy [monero-wallet-gui](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui) on android playstore?

Answer (score 1):

- [25$ one-time dev fee](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=en) to create an account on playstore (NB: it's full KYC'd)
- Minor build changes:

  - [target API level 30](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies) (currently 28)
  - `Release` build type (currently release builds produces debug apk)
  - [`make aab` instead of `make apk`](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)
  - [Sign the package](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)
- [Need to give up the signing private key to google](https://www.theregister.com/2021/07/01/android_app_bundle/). There's no way around it but there's [allegedly a way to verify that playstore produces legit APKs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/code-transparency)
- public URL that points to a [privacy policy since the app uses camera](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/android-permissions-privacy-policy/)
- Takes currently around 2 weeks for first app verifications
- Short description (<80 chars)
- Description
- At least 2 screenshots
- Logo with different resolutions
- 1 public email address